# Python: is there a way to sort a list from higher to lower

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following piece of code in python:

```
results = {}
....
results = sorted([(v, k) for (k, v) in results.items()])
....
return results[:limit]
```

`results` contains distances that are sorted in such a way the smaller distances are in the top of the list

Is there a way to sort this list in such a way the higher distances are in the top of `results`?
 Or, if we don't reverse the items is there a way to get the last items of `results` instead of the top results using `return results[:limit]`

Comment: you probably want `reverse=True` or/and `heapq` module

Comment: Do you care only for the top (or bottomly) ranked item? If so, you should look into using heaps (with the [heapq](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html?highlight=heapq) library).

Comment: Is it necessary to change the structure of `results`? If not, you can utilize the `key=` parameter of `sorted` to accomplish the same: `results = sorted(results.items(), key=lambda n: n[1], reverse=False)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the second question you ask, since @Ruzihm already answered the first, you can get the last items of `results` with:

```
return results[-limit:]
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the optional `reverse` parameter in the `sorted` function:

```
results= sorted([(v, k) for (k, v) in results.items()], reverse=True)
```

Comment: if this is the answer, then it's a super-classic duplicate you should refrain answering to

Comment: If you can find a suitable duplicate, please do link it instead of telling other people to do so.

Comment: please don't take it that way. We're not sure if this is a duplicate or not right now. It's just unclear.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer :)